# Is there another interface that I can use to manage the firewall in Windows 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, windows-firewall

I hate the interface for managing firewall in Widows Server 2008. Is there another GUI interface that I can use? Free is great but I'd even accept a 3rd party solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Must it be GUI?  You can use the "netsh" command line to change the firewall rules as well.  See [This Technet Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771920%28WS.10%29.aspx) for complete documentation on it.

Comment: I was looking for gui - I understand that it doesn't scale as well but sometimes it works better for quick fixes.